# How do you draw a phase potrait plot when one of the eigenvalues is zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have the system $X'=\begin{pmatrix}a&1\\2a&2\end{pmatrix}X$

I found the eigenvalues to be $\lambda=(a+2,0)$

and the eigenvectors to be $V=\left(\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\-a\end{pmatrix}\right)$ respectively.

which leads to the solution:

$X(t) = \alpha e^{(a+2)t}\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix}1\\-a\end{pmatrix}$

where

$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{matrix}\alpha e^{(a+2)t}+\beta\\2\alpha e^{(a+2)t}-a\beta\end{matrix}$

And I don't know how to draw the phase portrait for this one...

Here is me drawing a=-1,0,1[image]
I think my arrow directions are wrong, because arent they suppose to go to zero below the line? So a=-1 for example, would the lines below the equilibrium line (on the far right) point to zero below and above y=0?
Is this a bifurcation?

Comment: This looks helpful.

Comment: Yeah this is harder than I thought. I have no Idea how to draw this...

Comment: I added a picture.

Comment: In what way are they slightly off? The arrows?